# How to make a CPU Usage Control in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I want to make a control which is very similar to the one used in Windows Task Manager to show the CPU Performance something like a changing vertical Guage

Comment: So, what have you tried and how far did you get? Did you encounter any concrete problems that would make a proper SO question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the CPU usage values via `ManagementObjectSearcher` using WMI

To get the value, you do something like this

```
var info = ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\\localhost\root\CIMV2","SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor WHERE Name=\"_Total\"");
ManagementObject queryObj = info.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().First();
var cpuUsage = Convert.ToInt32(queryObj["PercentIdleTime"]);
```

Alternatively you can use the System.Diagnostics PerformanceCounter instead

```
PerformanceCounter cpu = new PerformanceCounter(){
    CategoryName = "Processor",
    CounterName = "% Processor Time",
    InstanceName = "_Total"
};

var yourCpuUsageValue = cpu.NextValue();
```

Comment: WMI is going to be a bit heavy if you want (semi) realtime updates.

Comment: That is a fair point.. guess he can use PerformanceCounter instead.. i'll amend my reply

Answer (score 1):

Got it...used a Progress Bar to show the values and used PerformanceCounter to get the cpu usage values.

Thanks

Comment: Great, glad it worked mate.  General practice is that you would add comments like this to your own question, or to the answer that answered your question.  Make sure that you mark the correct answer, since otherwise people will think it is unanswered.